# How to organize 3 nested loops in java?

Tags: java, loops, do-while

Here is my loops structure.

```
int k = 0;
do {
    ....                        

    do {
        fc = Recognize();
        ....
        do {
            ....
        } while(fc != false);

        k++;
    } while(k != 20);

    if (k == 20) {
        return;
    }
} while(true);
```

I need to end all loops when either `k` equals 20 or `fc` equals true.
I tried different ways to do this but failed. The code above is my last attempt. Need help in fixing that.

```
   grabber.start();
   int k=0;
   do {   
     grabber.stop();
     grabber.start();

     img = grabber.grab();
     if (img != null) {
       canvas.showImage(img);
       canvas.pack();
       cvWaitKey(0);
     }
     do {  
       fc=  Recognize();
       grabber.start();
       do {
         img = grabber.grab();
         if (img != null) {
            CvHaarClassifierCascade cascade = new 
            CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(XML_FILE));
            CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();
            CvSeq sign = cvHaarDetectObjects(img,
              cascade,storage, 1.5, 3,CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);

            cvClearMemStorage(storage);
            total_Faces = sign.total();     

            for(int i = 0; i < total_Faces; i++){
              CvRect r = new CvRect(cvGetSeqElem(sign, i));
              cvRectangle (img,
                cvPoint(r.x(),r.y()),
                cvPoint(r.width()+r.x(),r.height()+ r.y()),
                CvScalar.RED,2,CV_AA,0);

                x=r.x();
                y=r.y();
                h=r.height();
                w=r.width();
              }         

              cvFlip(img, img, 1);
              canvas.showImage(img);
              canvas.pack();
              cvWaitKey(0);
           }
         } while(fc!=false);

         k++;    
       }  while(k!=21);  
     } while(true);  
  }
```

Comment: You currently have an infinite loop if I'm reading it correctly.. You initialize `int k = 20;`, then when you are in the second level `do` you have `k++` and in the check of that same do-while-loop you check `while(k != 20);` At this point `k` is 21, and it keeps rising, so it will never leave this `do-while` loop in the code-snippet you've posted..

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen . It's k=0; in my code. I've mistaken when written the post.

Comment: Still very confusing... What does this code do? You are grabbing an image and displaying it if it is not null, then you do some 'recognizing' and grab another(?) image. If this latter image is not null you do some analysis on it and if you find something you put a rectagle on each of the objects you have found? Explain in words what you want to do.

Comment: @ГринюкАндрей I spent probably 10 minutes just to get the formatting somehow correct. Unfortunately seeing all the code ... makes it very clear, that it would need **extensive** amounts to do a "clean rewrite". And without the ability to run any tests while refactoring ... I guess I can't uphold my "promise" - you have to fix this mess yourself. My personal hint: throw it away; and start doing TDD. Write testcases, and step by step implement what needs to be implement. Even when fixing your existing code today, it is impossible to test and a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @Jägermeister What do u mean by "clean rewrite"? this code works fine for now. i just need to break all loops after fc==true or k==21. Tried label the  1rst loop but it doesnt work.

Comment: @ГринюкАндрей I already told you that I think your code is neither readable nor maintainable. And as it is written, you also don't have any unit tests for it. If that "works for you"; all fine. But if you are interested in learning to improve your coding skills, this source code offers many, many opportunities to exactly do that.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: don't do that.

Check out Clean code by Robert Martin; and understand & apply the [single layer of abstraction](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction) principle.

There are good reasons why various tools measure "code complexity" by especially looking for such kind of nested structures.

I understand that many people with a more "mathematical" background think that it is OK when computer programs resemble "mathematical" structures. But well: that is wrong. Computer programs are written ... to be read by humans. When you read a piece of source code, the main thing that counts is: how long does it take you to understand what is going on.

I guarantee you, no matter how you structure a loop in a loop in a loop; in one week from now you will have major difficulties to understand what is going on. Therefore it is worth to sit down for an hour or more to come up with a better solution. Unfortunately, your example doesn't show the real problem you are trying to solve; thus it is a hard to give concrete tips on how to do that in your case.

Comment: This answer is generic and doesn't address this question, which does have an easy and specific answer. Also, it is an over-generalization. I strongly disagree with the fact that nested loops are inherently bad.

Comment: @Jägermeister ok. here is a complete code. What's Your solution?

Comment: @Nico When you meet a blind person on the road, and the guy asks you "is there a lorry coming down the road?" any you answer "no"; that would be a specific answer to a specific question. But when the blind guy then decides to walk over the street, and is run over by some Tesla car ... that correct, specific answer wasn't too helpful?! What I am saying is: **this** code is way too complex. And just the **code** structure might hide various more bugs. Maybe there are places were loops in loops in loops are accepted; fine. But I have too many bad code like that to allow it pass by.

Comment: @Jägermeister telling the blind guy not to cross a road ever again isn't very helpful either

Comment: @Nico Sure. But actually, I didn't tell him to never cross the road. I suggested to step back and consider a option which he didn't hear of before.

Answer (score 0):

`while(k!=21 && fc){...}` is enough. Or `do {...} while(k!=21 && fc);` if need be. The outermost loop is useless as well as some of the `if`s in the middle.

Answer (score -1):

The only loop that needs to be written is

```
int k = 0;
do {
      fc = Recognize();
      k++  ;
   } while(k!=20 || fc );
```

Comment: I need different parts of a code to be executed not equal amount of times. thats why i need 3 loops.

Comment: Well this requirement was not specifed in the actual question. There was no reason for the downvote.

Comment: @ Nayan Sonthalia . I specified it now. and its not me who downvoted.